# Can I parse string to SQL code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a materialized view that requires slightly different filters between prod, dev, qa.

We have a variables table that stores random ids and I'm trying to find a way to store something like this in my variables table:

```
       prod_filter_values =  "(D.DEFID = 123 AND D.ATTRID IN (2, 3, 4)) OR
        (D.DEFID = 3112 AND D.ATTRID IN (3, 30, 34, 23, 4)) OR
        (D.DEFID = 379 AND D.ATTRID IN (3, 5, 8)) OR
        (D.DEFID = 3076 AND D.ATTRID = 5);"
```

Then I'd do something like `select * from variables_table where EVAL(prod_filter_values)`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can as other answers have explained.  However a better way would be to have this data driven - simply create tables in your various environments that have the corresponding magic numbers and join to that as required.

A second way is to have different views for the different environments with the numbers hard-coded there.

Anything that avoids building strings is going to be better for several reasons including having code in one place, stable code, no security/injection problems, no parse overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Lookup dynamic SQL:

https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01102

something like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from vars_table where ' || prod_filter_values;
```

Comment: You can bind variables, not the entire `where` clause. You'd have to concatenate into a single string instead.

Comment: better like this?

Comment: Oracle uses `||` for string concatenation, not `+`. You also have to select into something, or open a ref cursor instead, depending on what will be done with the results.